# Is it possible to configure Apple's Magic Mouse to be recognised on start up?

Tags: 10.10, wireless, mouse

This question may apply more roundly to all bluetooth mice but in my case I am dealing with an Apple Magic Mouse. I have followed the set up instructions here; https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicMouse
closely. I have even removed the mouse and started from scratch more than once repeating each step described carefully.

Every time the computer is started it does not see the Magic Mouse by default. I need to keep a wired mouse connected to the computer at all times which I use to log in with then connect the Magic Mouse, in a somewhat counter-intuitive exercise! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The following is an edit made to include responses to points made by others in response to my original question;

I believe I do use GDM as my understanding is it is default in Ubuntu 10.10. The only edit to the boot process I have made is this; http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/new-smooth-intelligent-plymouth-boot-screen-for-ubuntu/ I'm no expert, I think perhaps plymouth loads after gnome display manager? This plymouth theme is the only edit I've made to the boot process so although I'm not 100 percent certain as to what gnome display manager is, my login process is default apart from that. Would gdm affect this issue, eg, should I ensure I do use it or replace it with something else?

My Magic Mouse is second hand, so I have no way of knowing if it is paired to another computer. It quite possibly is but would be either impossible or at least very difficult for me to track down that computer. Does the magic mouse have its own memory and can this affect its ability to connect to my computer?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

For me this setup works quite well.

Some things you might want to check:

- Do you use the gnome display manager?
- Have you deconnected the mouse from all other computers it's has ever been paired with? My mouse connected automatically to my friends MacBook until I discovered that it was still paired to it.